# Having issues summarizing years as decades in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if someone could spot the reason why my query is returning an error at the very end. The situation I am trying to solve is

**For each decade since 1990 (1990, 2000, 2010), list the average MRSP of all books published in that decade, along with a count of copies sold and total sales $.**

I was able to figure out the decades part with the following code

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN date_published BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1999-12-31' THEN '1990'
WHEN date_published BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2009-12-31' THEN '2000'
WHEN date_published BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' THEN '2010'
ELSE 'Void'
END AS 'Decade', copies_sold
FROM book
```

However when I try to bring everything together in

```
SELECT 'Decade',
SUM(copies_sold) AS 'Copies Sold',
SUM(msrp*copies_sold) AS 'Total Sales',
SUM(msrp/copies_sold) AS 'Avg MSRP'

FROM
(SELECT *,
CASE WHEN date_published BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1999-12-31' THEN '1990'
WHEN date_published BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2009-12-31' THEN '2000'
WHEN date_published BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' THEN '2010'
ELSE 'Void'
END AS 'Decade', copies_sold
FROM book) 

FROM book
```

I get the following error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM book' at line 15"

Can anyone help me close this out? It would be super appreciated! The current fiddle is

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5464a4f1103bd4d6ed98e504be5ed7fe

The final output should look something like

Decade | Copies Sold | Total Sales| Avg MSRP
1990           5            10000          58

Comment: Please include the _exact_ output you want to see here.

Comment: You cannot have 2 from statement in the main query - the last from book is spurious -remove that then add the required sub query alias and deal with the duplicate copies sold error (it will be selected as part of the * so one of them needs to be aliased)

Comment: also do not use single `'` for database object.

Comment: You seem to have added duplicate FROM statement in your query. Since you are using a nested query your nested query acts as a table itself, and you should give your nested query table a name ( also known as an alias for derived table ). This works

`...ELSE 'Void' END AS 'Decade', copies_sold FROM book) b`

Comment: @AmirSaleem *This works* No. Duplicated column name `copies_sold` (1st from the asterisk and 2nd specified separately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exclude dates earlier than 1990 with a WHERE condition; there's no need to bother with them.

You can calculate decade more easily with just `10*FLOOR(YEAR(date_published)/10)`.

There's no need for a subquery, and you do need to group by your decade.

```
SELECT
    10*FLOOR(YEAR(date_published)/10) AS Decade,
    SUM(copies_sold) AS 'Copies Sold',
    SUM(msrp*copies_sold) AS 'Total Sales',
    SUM(msrp/copies_sold) AS 'Avg MSRP'
FROM book
WHERE date_published > '1989-12-31'
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Errorneous tokens commented.

```
SELECT 'Decade',
SUM(copies_sold) AS 'Copies Sold',
SUM(msrp*copies_sold) AS 'Total Sales',
SUM(msrp/copies_sold) AS 'Avg MSRP'

FROM
(SELECT *,
CASE WHEN date_published BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1999-12-31' THEN '1990'
WHEN date_published BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2009-12-31' THEN '2000'
WHEN date_published BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' THEN '2010'
ELSE 'Void'
END AS 'Decade' /* , copies_sold */
FROM book) 

/* FROM */ book
```

`copies_sold` commented because this column is already selected in `SELECT *`.

`FROM` commented because `book` is subquery alias, not data source.